# Is it possible to move the text cursor/ caret multiple characters at once using C++?

Tags: operating-system, clipboard, caret

I'm writing an application that pastes strings into any given editor. After selecting something to paste my application programmatically looses focus, giving it to the application that had focus before. It then sends Ctrl+V to the OS to paste it in the other application. I want to be able to set the position of the cursor after pasting. Currently a pasted text will always leave the cursor at the end of the text.

I already tried sending multiple Arrow Left presses to the OS, so for example if I wanted:

```
Hello $CURSOR_POSITION$World
                       54321
```

I would send 5 times ArrowLeft after pasting "Hello World". This is very slow tho as every single Arrow Left key is processed serparetly (moves left about once per second). As the strings can get very long using Ctrl+ArrowLeft to skip entire words does not solve the problem.

I already looked into ANSI-Codes, they only seem to work in consoles though, I want it to work in every editor.

Is there a way to achieve this using C++? Something like moveCursorLeft(5)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this is *very* operating system dependent, it helps if you tell us *what* operating system you're using.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm developing for Windows, Linux and Mac. So solutions for all operating systems are welcome, so I can implement it seperatly if necessary.